# HDI: Implement record level security in a lightswitch application

Tags: security, visual-studio-lightswitch

Looking for general guidance on implementing row/record level security in a lightswitch application.

Classic Example, Allow users to only edit their entries while allowing management to edit all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might give you some idea: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mthalman/archive/2010/09/07/filtering-data-based-on-current-user-in-lightswitch-apps.aspx

LS V2 will implement row-level security: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/LightSwitchDev11Beta/thread/7e0a9572-842e-4d5e-a613-71e49c160c58

From the LS Team Blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2012/04/17/filtering-data-using-entity-set-filters-michael-simons.aspx